# AutoModelForSequenceClassification requires the PyTorch library but it was not found in your environment

Tags: python, pytorch, roberta

I am trying to use the roberta transformer and a pre-trained model but I keep getting this error:

```
    ImportError: 
AutoModelForSequenceClassification requires the PyTorch library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and follow the ones that match your environment.
```

Here's my code:

```
# Tasks:
# emoji, emotion, hate, irony, offensive, sentiment
# stance/abortion, stance/atheism, stance/climate, stance/feminist, stance/hillary

task='sentiment'
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
# download label mapping
labels=[]
mapping_link = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardiffnlp/tweeteval/main/datasets/{task}/mapping.txt"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)
labels=[]
mapping_link = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardiffnlp/tweeteval/main/datasets/{task}/mapping.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(mapping_link) as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    csvreader = csv.reader(html, delimiter='\t')
labels = [row[1] for row in csvreader if len(row) > 1]
```

I made sure that PyTorch is installed and working:

[image]

Comment: The error says that it isn't found in your environment. Are you running a venv? If so, is PyTorch installed in it?

Comment: No, I am not running a venv

Answer (score 31):

I was having the same issue. It was solved for me by restarting the kernel.

Comment: Yes, we should restart the kernel.

Answer (score 14):

You need to install Pytorch first before import the HuggingFace Transformer.

Otherwise you'll have to restart the kernel